# 3d tiles branch on xampp not working

Tags: javascript, xampp, cesiumjs

I have checked out [3d-tiles](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/3d-tiles) branch of Cesium but I am getting 404 errors for Cesium.js and Cesium.css for basic HelloWorld page.
And a long list of 404 errors in console for a 3d tiles page from sandcastle. Few of them are for files listed below:

```
Source/Shaders/AdjustTranslucentFS.js 
Source/Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceFS.js 
Source/Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceVS.js
```

etc..

I am using Xampp server on Windows 7.

What am I missing to get this working? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : This code base is not built according to process documented [here](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/3d-tiles/Documentation/Contributors/BuildGuide). so the Build directory is missing. How to get this built in Xampp environment as I am not familiar with node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the missing files you mention are generated as part of the Cesium build.  The custom build actions are written in JavaScript for Node.js, and can be run as outlined in the [Build Guide](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/3d-tiles/Documentation/Contributors/BuildGuide) that you already linked to.

Cesium doesn't build directly under Xampp, as that stack is based on PHP and Perl, not JavaScript.  Instead, if you wish to use a Cesium branch as opposed to an official release of Cesium, you'll need to install Node.js and follow the build steps at least once.  Once the branch is built, then you can host it with Xampp/Apache.

You could even perform the build step on another machine, if you have a means of copying the result to the host machine.  This way you could avoid the need to install Node.js on the host.

Comment: this worked on my office machine. But on my PC I don't see `Build/Cesium/Cesium.js` after I build the project with `npm run build` command. Is there any way to debug why is it now getting built properly?

Comment: To get that file, you need to build, combine, and minify.  As a shortcut to all that, you can just type `npm run release`.  This may take about 5 minutes to run.